# How do you insert a row/column in a WPF Grid?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, xaml, grid, expression-blend

Anyone have any suggestions on how to insert a row or column in a WPF Grid using (preferably) Visual Studio 2008?

It's no problem to add a new `RowDefinition` or `ColumnDefinition`, but I'm really not too excited about the prospect of incrementing the `Grid.Row` or `Grid.Column` for the large number of cells that are affected by the insertion. Has anyone come up with a clever way to automate this (perhaps with a regular expression find/replace operation)?

If this can't be done in Studio, can it be done in Blend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use smaller size grids in your applications and then put those grids inside other grids, or try some of the WPF grid tools by [Karl on WPF](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/xaml-power-toys/)

VS2010 looks like it will have a better editor.

Blend is fairly good at inserting rows - when in design edit mode you can click the edge to add a row; Blend will then adjust your layout to look the same with the edited row. You will still need to manually move elements around the grid, but it should be less work overall.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and used [vim](http://www.vim.org/) to increment the row numbers. This was my expression:

```
:.,$s/\(Grid.Row="\)\(\d\+\)/\=join([submatch(1),submatch(2)+1],'')/
```

Explanation:

<kbd>`:.,$s`</kbd> substitute (`:s`) from the current line (`.`) until the end of the file (`$`)

<kbd>`/\(Grid.Row="\)\(\d\+\)/`</kbd> searches for `Grid.Row="` followed by a 1 or more digit number (`\d\+`). Both parts are between `\(` and `\)` to use the submatch function.

<kbd>`\=join([`... `],'')`</kbd> joins the strings in the array between `[` and `]`.

<kbd>`submatch(1)`</kbd>, the first submatch, ie the text `Grid.Row="`/

<kbd>`submatch(2)+1`</kbd>, the second submatch, ie the number incremented with 1.